# 20 amp, 220v, 2 pole GFCI Breaker

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

Do I need a neutral white wire to install a 220v GFCI breaker in the main panel ?

Currently have 220v, 2 pole red hot, black hot and green ground in the circuit running pool pump timer and pump.

Or can I use the green wire as neutral?
I believe the answer is no.

Please advise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need a neutral "load" wire if you're running only 240V load. The GFCI will detect any imbalance between the two phases and trip if one occurs.  See picture below.

[image]

The green wire can never be used for anything but a ground.

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward.

For a 240V GFCI device, it will have a neutral pigtail.  That must be hooked up, for the purpose of powering the GFCI device itself.

However once that's hooked up, you are welcome to attach a 240V circuit hot-hot only.

Remember white wires used as hot need to marked with tape to indicate they are hots. Otherwise someone might put them on the GFCI neutral!